# What are the new Sybase ASE/REP patches SPxxx?

Tags: sap-ase, sybase-rs

Sybase is going to release some new ASE/REP patches SP100 then SP101 instead of ESD#

What will be the differences between ESD# and SP100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to SAP/Sybase it's just name change to fall in line with the SAP way of doing things, as they continue to integrate product lines.  SP stands for *Support Package*, where ESD stands for *Electronic Software Distribution*, but functionally they are both patches to prior software releases.

Some of the expected changes between versions of ASE can be found here:
http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1038641

More about the change in patch naming:
http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1099335

Rob Verschoor, one of the SAP Sybase Engineers just posted a blog about this very topic:
http://scn.sap.com/community/sybase-ase-custom-applications/blog/2013/06/02/sybase-ases-version-numbering-goes-the-sap-way

Comment: Thanks Michael for the links!!

Comment: Support told me that REP15.7.1 SP100 will require a "full upgrade" and not a simple binary overlay meaning that we will have to follow a detailed procedure to apply this patch.

Comment: I guess that makes sense, to start a new product release style.